# Aplicacion Android se detiene al usar camara (onDestroy)

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit, google-play-services

Tengo una aplicación android la cual en un cierto punto al usuario le solicito una evidencia fotografica, antes de la agregar los servicios de google **play services** y **firebase** funcionaba sin problemas.

El manifest ya esta configurado por si se va en segundo plano mantenga los cambios realizados.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityLogin"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:multiprocess="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityMain"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:multiprocess="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <!-- INSTALL PACKAGE
        <activity android:name=".PackageInstallerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSTALL_PACKAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSTALL_PACKAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UninstallerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.UNINSTALL_PACKAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        INSTALL PACKAGE-->

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:multiprocess="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
        <receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
           android:name=".WifiReceiver$WifiActiveService"
           android:icon="@drawable/binoculars"
           android:label="LecturasService" />

        <!--<providers
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>-->

    </application>
```

Los servicios agregados son los siguientes:

**build.gradle**

```
.....
    dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
        }
.....
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        }
    }
....
```

**app>build.gradle**

```
...
dependencies {

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    /*Retrofit JSON Parsing*/
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    /*Play Services*/
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    /*Firebase Crash*/
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.2.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    /*Otros*/
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'
```

**Metodo que utilizo para ejecutar o solicitar la camara.**

```
public void intentTakePhoto(int codeResult)
    {
        boolean result = Permission.checkPermissionCamera(ActivityMain.this);
        Log.e("intentTakePhoto: ", " = "+result);
        if (result)
        {
            if(contrato.getCount()>0)
            {
                imageName = "/DIRAPP/" + pref.getText() + "_" + pos.getSelectedItem().toString() + "_" + codeResult + ".jpg";
                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + imageName);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                Uri Foto = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+ ".provider", file);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23)
                {
                    Log.e("intentTakePhoto: ", ">21");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Foto);
                }else
                {
                    Log.e("intentTakePhoto: ", "Normal");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                }
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("stock",stock.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
                startActivityForResult(intent, codeResult);
            }else{
                mostrarAlerta("No hay datos.");
            }
        }else{
            mostrarAlerta("No tiene permisos para usar la camara");
        }
    }
```

Despues de tomar la evidencia fotografica, o al abrir la camara la aplicación se reinicia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el logcat muestra un error al momento de cerrarce la aplicacion. Copia ese mensaje y publicalo y asi podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Verificastes si tenias los permisos necesarios en el Manifest para usar la cámara??

Comment: ayudaria mucho tener el log de la ejecución.

Comment: los permisos ya estan en el manisfest y hasta soporte para 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el problema esté en el método Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ya que el directorio podría no estar disponible en el momento de ejecutarse.

Para comprobar el estado del directorio puedes usar el método Environment.getExternalStorageState() que te devolverá un String con el estado del almacenamiento externo y que puede ser uno de estos valores (MEDIA_UNKNOWN, MEDIA_REMOVED, MEDIA_UNMOUNTED, MEDIA_CHECKING, MEDIA_NOFS, MEDIA_MOUNTED, MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY, MEDIA_SHARED, MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL, or MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE)

Además getExternalStorageDirectory() requiere los permisos WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  y READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Si estás usando un API mínimo superior a KITKAT puedes utilizar en su lugar getExternalFilesDir(String) o getExternalCacheDir() ya que no requieren permisos de escritura ni lectura.

Espero que te sirva de algo.

Comment: Eso fue una de las primeras cosas que verifique, y no hay problema con ello., de hecho cuando se elimina la carpeta suponiendo que es usuario root se vuelve a crear automaticamente.

Comment: Y bueno en si la aplicación no se destruye completamente como lo hace cuando hay un error ahi si la aplicación practicamente se detiene, en cambio lo que pasa aqui es que la aplicación se reinicia entra nuevamente en el onCreate y aquí es donde me causa problemas no debe de recrear los componentes por que afecta a la interacción con el usuario.

Comment: La configuración para mantener los cambios de la actividad ya esta configurada y funciona. Siempre y cuando no se use la camara, este error no siempre pasa, ejemplo: si el usuario usa la aplicación le puede funcionar 1,2,3,4,5 veces de manaera correcta y de repente a la 6ta se reinicia y asi sucesivamente.